# Sqlalchemy RETURNING scalar

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

i was messing around with the sqlalchemy return clause, consider the following code

```
stmt = insert(A).values({"data": "data", "id":2}).returning(A)
result = await session.execute(stmt)
print(type(result.scalar()))
```

the output just prints a integer

but if I use a `select` statement instead of return it gives the mapped row object?

```
stmt = select(A).where(A.id == 2)
result = await session.execute(stmt)
print(type(result.scalar()))
```

why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

The first execution returns the tuple `(2, 'data')`, the second  `(<__main__.A object at 0x7f32b9fbefe0>,)`.  However calling [result.scalar](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html?highlight=scalar#sqlalchemy.engine.Result.scalar) will

> Fetch the first column of the first row, and close the result set.

Thus you get `2` for the first execution, but a model instance for the second.